# Большое O для вставки в коллекцию

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, stl, сложность

Как посчитать большое О для вставки в коллекцию?

Коллекция имеет вид:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, tokens> Consumers;  
typedef std::unordered_set<std::string> Tokens;
```

Каким образом оно расчитывается? Произведение сложности вставки в `unordered_set` и сложности вставки в `map`, или иным образом?

Comment: Формально - вставка одного элемента в map - [O(lg N)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), в unordered_set - [O(1) в среднем](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert).

Comment: А можно ли посчитать суммарную сложность в этом случае?

Comment: `tokens` и `Tokens`? Язык С++ является чувствительным к регистру.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Нет, вы неправы. Зависит от того, чего и сколько вставлять, и еще и от того, в каком порядке.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы правильно посчитать сложность вставки, выборки или поиска рандомного элемента в контейнере в первую очередь нужно понимать как этот контейнер сохраняется в памяти. Или это участок память без разрывов, или это связной список или дерево или хештейбл и т.п. Понимая это ,понять эффективность контейнеров станет намного проще, а с таким подходом "просто заучить" это не даст никакого понимая. 
Для `std::map` и `std::unordered_map` ну нужно самостоятельно ничего считать, можно посмотреть их эффективность по всем операциям [здесь](http://john-ahlgren.blogspot.com/2013/10/stl-container-performance.html).

Comment: Остальные ответы или дали конкретную формулу, или посоветовали провести эксперимент. У вас ничего кроме общеговорильни. Это я поясняю, почему ставлю минус.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от порядка.

Если вставляем по `m` строк в `n` `unordered_set`, имеем `O(mn)+O(log n)`, т.е. вообще говоря `O(mn)`.

Если вставляем `n` пустых `unordered_set` в `map`, а потом случайным образом (с поиском в `map`!) заполняем их `m` строками каждый, то `O(log n)+O(m*n*log n)`, т.е. `O(mn*log n)`.

И не забываем, что `unordered_set` имеет `O(1)` в среднем, но может иметь при невезении и `O(n)`...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: `Если вставляем по m строк в n unordered_set, имеем O(mn)+O(log n), т.е. вообще говоря O(mn)`

Этот момент не очень понятен. Почему вставка в `hashtable` `O(log n)`? И почему `O(mn)` это не `O(n)`?

Comment: @raviga Вставка в конкретную таблицу - `O(1)`, но ее еще нужно найти - а это - `O(log n)`. `O(mn)` не `O(n)`, потому что никто не гарантирует, что `m` - константа. Вдруг у вас `n^2` строк в каждую из `n` таблиц? и получите вы `O(n^3)` :) А вообще, это очень недопонимаемая многими тема, но, увы, она куда больше, чем можно рассказать в одном вопросе/ответе. Простейший пример с порядком вычислений - тот же поиск в массиве m раз - если он несортирован, имеем O(mn), если отсортировать - O((m+n)*log n). Да, вот так вот и записывается :) - читайте Кнута или Кормена...

Comment: не уверен, что все хорошо понял, но понял, что надо это точно перечитать

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из [определения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5)

> фраза «сложность алгоритма есть **O(f(n))**» означает, что с увеличением параметра **n**, характеризующего количество входной информации алгоритма, время работы алгоритма будет возрастать не быстрее, чем некоторая константа, умноженная на **f(n)**;

вы можете сами посчитать "большое О" проведя эксперимент (например вставка 100_000 элементов), и подобрав аппроксимационную функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что собираешься вставлять, если пару std::string и Tokens то будет сложность map( O(logn)), тк он по sting`е просто положит unordered_set. Если же достать по std::string unordered_set и вставить уже в него, тогда будет сумма сложностей. Так как сначала ищем нужный unordered_set O(logN) а потом вставляем в него O(1).